# How to add "date modified" as a permanent option for sorting files in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, date-modified

I would like the "date modified" option to be permanently shown on every folder in Windows Explorer when I right click and choose "sort" and also on the bar above the content of the folder.

Right now I have to add "date modified" from `right click > sort > more...` and the again right click and choose it each time for each folder! I use this option very much and it's making me angry most of the time. Actually Windows won't learn it at all itself!

Currently, I use Windows 7. I would like to know how to add this option permanently in Windows 7 and also other versions of Windows if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows 7 (and higher) has settings per Folder-type.

If you want all your subfolders to have the same columns you need to set you preferences once in the root-folder and then in `Properties` > `Customize` choose to apply this type (and settings) to all subfolders.

Make sure to also do `Organize` > `Folder and search options`, `View` and choose <kbd>Reseet Folders</kbd> and <kbd>Apply to folders</kbd> to reset already know settings for certain folders. (Or else they will still be of the old type)

In Windows XP it was possible to uncheck "Save settings per folder" which resulted in your preferences being for all folders. Windows 7 does it according to type.

[image]

Comment: this saving per folder type was added in Vista, not Windows 7.